# Creating Azure Function Project with CLI

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

After installing Azure Functions Core Tools with `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@3 --unsafe-perm true`, I assumed the `func init --ProjectName` command would create the Azure Functions Project with AzureFunctionsVersion v3 but instead it created with v2 in the project file:

.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After setting the environment variable `CLI_DEBUG=1` and rerunning the func init command I've realized, it triggers following commands:

```
> dotnet new --install "C:\Users\murat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\templates\itemTemplates.3.0.10405.nupkg"
> dotnet new --install "C:\Users\murat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\templates\projectTemplates.3.0.10405.nupkg"
> dotnet new func --AzureFunctionsVersion v2 --name ProjectName --StorageConnectionStringValue "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"

> dotnet new --uninstall "C:\Users\murat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\templates\itemTemplates.3.0.10405.nupkg"
> dotnet new --uninstall "C:\Users\murat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\templates\projectTemplates.3.0.10405.nupkg"
```

clearly it calls the `--AzureFunctionsVersion v2` argument. 
**Is this default behavior?**

Because if I use the dotnet new func command in a folder, or use VS2019 AzureFunctions v3 Project, it sets AzureFunctionsVersion to **v3**

After digging into AcureFunctionsCoreTools source code, i found following code in DeployDotnetProject method of DotnetHelpers class:

```cs
public async static Task DeployDotnetProject(string Name, bool force)
{
    await TemplateOperation(async () =>
    {
        var connectionString = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)
            ? $"--StorageConnectionStringValue \"{Constants.StorageEmulatorConnectionString}\""
            : string.Empty;
        var exe = new Executable("dotnet", $"new func --AzureFunctionsVersion v2 --name {Name} {connectionString} {(force ? "--force" : string.Empty)}");
        var exitCode = await exe.RunAsync(o => { }, e => ColoredConsole.Error.WriteLine(ErrorColor(e)));
        if (exitCode != 0)
        {
            throw new CliException("Error creating project template");
        }
    });
}
```

Do we still need this `--AzureFunctionsVersion v2` argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, on usual, you will get a project like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Have a look of [this Blog](https://dev.to/azure/develop-azure-functions-using-net-core-3-0-gcm), you can choose to create azure function v3 by Visual Studio 2019 16.4 or newer. It will create v3 successfully.

And have a look of this: [The Azure CLI may be still in the situation of create v2 by default](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Functions-3.x-go-live-work-items).

By the way, you can change the `AzureFunctionsVersion` of the Function App that 
you created using CLI to v3. It seems no matter what Version you set, the RunTime Verison is still 3.0.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned earlier, VS2019 creates the v3 without any issues, but the link you provided [The Azure CLI may be still in the situation of create v2 by default](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Functions-3.x-go-live-work-items) clearly shows v2 is still the default.